# What are some scientific laws of political science?

Tags: political-science

Are there laws in political science like there are laws in economics(E.g.law of demand)?

Comment: google up *political theorems* which will provide better searching differentiation from "laws passed by politicians" .  one example would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duverger's_law  people here refer to them every so often.  but... this is a bit of a list type of question which isn't all that suited for this site.